# Are directional derivatives at a point from opposite directions opposite or equal?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am very new to multivariable calculus, so I proved something this morning that surprised me.

$f: A \subset R \to R$

I proved two things:

Firstly, f is differentiable at $x$ if and only if  $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(x+t) - f(x)}{t} \in R$

Secondly, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x) = vf'(x)$. $v$ is directional vector. In this situation, v can either be $1$ or $-1$ as $dim(R) = 1$.

It surprised me that directional derivative at a point $x_0$ from opposite directions are not only different but also opposite.

In other words, $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(x+t) - f(x)}{t} = -\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(x - t) - f(x)}{t} $

I want to know if my final conclusion is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Suppose we're walking uphill at a particular location $x$. If we reverse direction at $x$, are we walking uphill or downhill?

Comment: You are correct. The directional derivative is the rate of change of the function value at your location *as you move in the given direction*.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!